# Access Violation upon Returning? How do I go about debugging this?

Tags: c++, debugging, segmentation-fault, access-violation

Our code logs various meaningful events. Usually logging works just fine, but today the log function is causing Access Violation upon returning. I'm guessing the heap was corrupted somehow, but it's not really clear to me why. The log function works pretty much in all circumstances, but now I'm logging a slightly longer file name. Where am I failing to see the problem here?

```
std::string Format(const char* fmt, ...)
{
    char buf[1 << 16]; // 65536
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vsprintf(buf, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    return std::string(buf);
} // <-- Access Violation (0xC0000005) upon returning


#define LOG_DEBUG(fmt, ...)                                      \
{                                                                \
    ILogger* logger = LoggerFactory::GetLogger();                \
    if (logger)                                                  \
    {                                                            \
        std::string log = Format(fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__);            \
        logger->WriteLog(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, log.c_str());          \
    }                                                            \
}


static int doSomething(char* szMsg, const int nLength, ...)
{
    // Normally, this executes just fine.
    LOG_DEBUG("Message = %s, length = %d", szMsg, nLength);

    // ... do some things
}
```

The program exits with the message: `0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.`. That address seems suspicious to me, why would it be maxed out?

For what it's worth the `szMsg` is assigned to a very long string of the form:

```
application_specific_data\rϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷ
ϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷ
ϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷ
ϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷ
ϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷϷ
```

And `nLength` is `65536`.

Anyways, I'm not really sure how think through this kind of issue, even if there isn't an explicit answer to this exact scenario, how can I debug this? What should I pay attention to? What can I ignore?

Comment: It looks like `szMsg` is not a null-terminated string, leading to *undefined behavior*. What likely is happening is that you go out of bounds of `buf` in the `Format` function because of the unterminated message. One quick fix is to use `std::vsnprintf` instead, which will protect against buffer overflows. An even better fix is to not use macros or old C-style varargs (see [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format), or [the format library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) it's based on, for help with that)

Comment: *"a very long string of the form"* -- How long? Less than 65,510?

Comment: Curious, why such construction + comment `char buf[1 << 16]; // 65536` instead of the more clear `char buf[65536];`?

Comment: Long string is probably occupying 65536 or more bytes. FWIW, this is only happening in a Debug x64 build.

Comment: `Format` has a buffer that is 65536 long, and then you try to log a message where `szMsg` is 65536 long? Then you also have to add "Message =" and "Length = 65536" to that, and it all adds up to at least 25 bytes of buffer overrun - if `Format` is made on the stack, then you may just have overwritten the return address, which kinda meshes with Google saying: "The 0xC0000005 error means that a program is trying to execute data as a code from non-executable parts of memory."

Comment: If your very long string is longer than 65535, it's obvious you've got an overflow problem with the `buf` array. Try `char buf[200000];` and see if the problem goes away. BTW if you want to say `65536` say `65536` instead of the less obvious `1<<16`.

Comment: Primary advice would be **do not do C** in C++. C++ has offered you all kinds of safeguards against UB and unmaintainable code; yet you discarded all. C++20 has the typesafe `std::format` for the very same purpose and its reference implementation is available as open-source **{fmt}** library. If you still want to do it yourself, at least use safer modern constructs(variadic templates, `std::to_chars`...). `printf` and C variadic functions must be retired and avoided - except for compatibility with C APIs.

Answer (score 4):

Access violation upon return is almost always the result of corrupting ***not*** the heap, but ***the stack***.

Specifically, in this case, the return address on the stack has been overwritten with 0xffffffff. This very often happens when you overflow a local buffer.

Obviously, the buffer that gets overflown is that `char buf[1 << 16];`

This can happen if you have a string which is longer than the buffer size, and this can in turn very easily happen if you accidentally have a string which you forgot to null-terminate.

To protect yourself against this problem ***never use*** `vsprintf()` (in my opinion the function should not even exist) always use `vsnprintf()`. This will not fix the bug that creates an awfully long string, but it will save your program from crashing and burning due to that bug.